# String expression interpolation support in java scripting engines

Tags: java, groovy, nashorn, java-scripting-engine

I'm using groovy/nashorn as java engine but not able to interpolate Strings.

```
jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine  scriptEngine =(NashornScriptEngine) factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
ScriptContext context = scriptEngine.getContext();
Bindings bindings = context.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("x","Guest");
engine.eval("Hello, ${x}",context);
```

But I'm getting javax.script.ScriptException.
Is Sttring interpolation supported?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two things worth mentioning:

- if you want to evaluate Groovy script, you might need to use

  ```
  new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("groovy");
  ```
- the script passed to `engine.eval()` method has to be a valid Groovy code. The script code you passed to the eval method is not a valid Groovy code - you expect to interpolate a string, but you didn't put it inside the double quotes.

Consider the following example:

```java
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("groovy");
ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
Bindings bindings = context.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("x","Guest");
Object result = engine.eval("\"Hello, ${x}\"", context);

System.out.println(result);
```

The output:

```
Hello, Guest
```

Alternatively, you may pass a Groovy script that prints the interpolated script. In this case the code may look like this:

```java
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("groovy");
ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
Bindings bindings = context.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("x","Guest");
engine.eval("println \"Hello, ${x}\"", context);
```

It produces the same output, but does not assign `Hello, Guest` to a variable.